# How to update table based on maximum date of a certain group of rows

Tags: sqlite

I have this table that I want to update one of its column based on the maximum value of another.

For example:

```
Table with the following columns
Id  title  startDate   groupId    endDate
```

I want to basically update all the endDate of all the rows of the in which I would replace the endDate with the maximum value of startDate among all the rows with the same groupId

For example

Table can have initally

```
1 ,grp1, 2013-09-01 14:45, 1, ''
2 ,grp1, 2013-10-01 15:45, 1, ''
3 ,grp1, 2013-11-01 16:45, 1, ''       <----Row with the maximum (most future startDate)
4 ,grp2, 2013-09-01 14:45, 2, ''
5 ,grp2, 2013-10-01 14:45, 2, ''       <----Row with the maximum (most future startDate)
6 ,grp2, 2013-08-01 14:45, 2, ''
```

So I want to be able to run the query so Table looks like

```
1 ,grp1, 2013-09-01 14:45, 1, 2013-11-01 16:45
2 ,grp1, 2013-10-01 15:45, 1, 2013-11-01 16:45
3 ,grp1, 2013-11-01 16:45, 1, 2013-11-01 16:45
4 ,grp2, 2013-09-01 14:45, 2, 2013-10-01 14:45
5 ,grp2, 2013-10-01 14:45, 2, 2013-10-01 14:45
6 ,grp2, 2013-08-01 14:45, 2, 2013-10-01 14:45
```

How can this be achieved in "SqlLite" query?

Comment: @Meistro See mouse-over text of the sql tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a subquery to look up the corresponding value:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET endDate = (SELECT MAX(T2.startDate)
               FROM MyTable AS T2
               WHERE T2.groupId = MyTable.groupId)
```